# math and mathematica not working in Debian command line

Tags: linux, command-line, installation

I am asking this question because I can't find solution anywhere.
On the Mathematica website it says to start Mathematica type `mathematica` and to start the kernel just type `math`. But these commands are not working.

I am using Debian Stretch (just installed a few days ago) and a trial copy, downloaded from official site, with 14 days remaining. Is it because trials can't run in command line in Linux?

I have installed Mathematica 11.0.1 on Windows on the same computer. Will I need a separate license for linux? (I installed 11.2.0 in Linux, but can happily go back to 11.0.1 if the license is available for Linux).

If I have to buy a license then I would rather have Mathematica 10 as given in Raspbian but I don't know the repository. Kindly give a link to repository where I can download Mathematica 10 for Debian.

I am new to Linux and I am experimenting on/with Debian, and I don't want to change operating system just yet, so if I can add a repository in Debian that would be great.

Comment: This is not an official Wolfram Research site. I think your questions would be better asked of Wolfram Research tech support than asked here.

Comment: Have you installed Mathematica before trying to use it?  When installing it, did you let the installer create symlinks to the `math` and `mathematica` binaries?  If not, create the symlinks manually. Look for the executables in the location where you installed Mathematica, typically `/opt/Wolfram/Mathematica` or `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica`

Comment: There's no repository you can use. You need to download the installer from Wolfram and install the software.  The Raspberry Pi version does not work on x86 systems (i.e. "normal computers").  Licensing questions are off-topic here: contact Wolfram with those.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a novice in linux so I have no idea what symlinks are however while installing it asked me for integration and i said yes, but it looks like that did not work or maybe symlinks are something else. could you guide me to how to do that?

However there is a folder called Executables in path
/bin/sh/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/Executables
and there are some files two are named mathematica and math but I can't run or execute them using ./math or ./mathematica command from terminal even when I am in the folder, and double clicking opens them .like text file.